# Use a for loop in vimscript to automate autocmd-calls

Tags: vim

I have different vim-scripts for different filetypes

```
.
├── .vim
│   ├── vimrc-c.vim
│   ├── vimrc-cpp.vim
│   ├── vimrc-default.vim
│   ├── vimrc-lisp.vim
│   ├── vimrc-pl.vim
│   └── vimrc-vim.vim
└── .vimrc
```

and my first solution was

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *      source $HOME/.vim/vimrc-default.vim

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.c    source $HOME/.vim/vimrc-c.vim
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cpp  source $HOME/.vim/vimrc-cpp.vim
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.lisp source $HOME/.vim/vimrc-lisp.vim
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.pl   source $HOME/.vim/vimrc-pl.vim
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.vim  source $HOME/.vim/vimrc-vim.vim
```

but i would like do replace that by a for loop - since it's an simple repetition - in a way like

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *      source $HOME/.vim/vimrc-default.vim
let s:extensions =
    \[
    \c,
    \cpp,
    \lisp,
    \pl,
    \vim,
    \]

for ext in s:extensions
    au BufNewFile,BufRead '*' . ext    source $HOME . "/.vim/vimrc-" . ext . '.vim'
endfor
```

but that's not working. I don't get an error though, so I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim already has a built-in mechanism for sourcing filetype-specific configuration files so reimplementing it, and in a non-portable way to boot, is totally pointless.

Here is how your directory structure should look like:

```
.
├── .vim/
│   └── after/
│       └── ftplugin/
│           ├── c.vim
│           ├── cpp.vim
│           ├── lisp.vim
│           ├── perl.vim
│           └── vim.vim
└── .vimrc
```

The only requirement is to have the line below in your `vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

See `:help filetypes`.

---

A few notes:

- The filename of your "ftplugins" matches the name of the filetype, not the extension. For example, Perl files have a `.pl` extension but their filetype is `perl`, so your ftplugin should be called `perl.vim`.
- Whatever you have put in your `vimrc-default.vim` should be in your `vimrc`.